# On form submit item values are getting reset

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a single web page using nodejs expressjs and mongoDB .In my page I have 2 text boxes which defines the filter clause for the collection in mongoDB.And I have a html table which shows the documents of the collection.When I pass the text box values filtering is working fine and the table shows the filtered documents. But for every page submit action , the text boxes are defaulted to null .I would like to persist the values in text box . Advice me please

My .ejs file is as follows

```
<body >  
<% include partials/nav %>
<h1>Portware Orders by Symbol TCA Report</h1>
<form name="getuser",method="post",action="/users">
Column name:<br>
<input type="text" name="colname">
<br>
Column value:<br>
<input type="text" name="colvalue">  
<button type="submit" value="Search" class="submitButton">Search</button>
</form>  
<div id="table-scroll" >
<table   align="center">
<tr style="width:200px">
<th>Symbol</th>
<th>Order_id</th>
</tr>
<% users.forEach(function(user) { %>
<tr style="width:100%">
<td ><%= user.symbol %></td>
<td><%= user.order_id %></td>
</tr>
<% }); %>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

and my index.js file is as follows

```
router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
var db = req.db;
var users = db.get('users');
var col_name=req.params.colname;
var col_value=req.params.colvalue;
var query={};
query[col_name]=col_value;
users.find(query,{limit: 10000},function(e, docs){
res.render('users', { 
title: 'Users',
'users': docs     
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried setting the value of the text box ? Something like: `document.getElementsByName('colname')[0].value = email;`
or with jQuery:

```
$('input[name=colname]')val('email')
```

Comment: I did. But page refresh happens at the end of it . Hence the value is going off.

Comment: You can prevent that default behaviour by setting preventDefault() on the event that triggers the form submit.

Comment: I want the page to submit also

Comment: That will not prevent the submit

Comment: Hi Sandeep .. When I add event.preventDefault , page is not getting submitted